# I sent the variable using javascript but the result is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, get

1. Javascript function I used to send the variable "dir"

   ```
   function getSelectVar1(obj){
       location.href = '<?=$THIS_FILE?>?dir=' + obj.value;
   }
   ```
2. The form I used to send the variable "dir".

   ```
   <FORM name=directoryForm method=GET ACTION='$PHP_SELF'>
       <tr class='headercontent'>
           <td  align=center width='240' class='header' >Select Directory </td>
           <td  width='460'>
               <SELECT style='background:c0c0c0;' NAME=dir  id='dir' onChange='getSelectVar1(dir)'>";
                   if ( $DIR_PATH != '.' ) {
                       echo "<OPTION VALUE='.'> Problem All </OPTION>";
                   }

                   echo "<OPTION VALUE='$DIR_PATH' selected>$DIR_PATH_RESULT</OPTION>";

                   $z = 0;
                   while( $z < $data_num ) {
                       if ( is_dir("$DIR_PATH/$other_FILES[$z]") && $other_FILES[$z] != '.' && $other_FILES[$z] != '..') {
                           echo "<OPTION VALUE='$DIR_PATH/$other_FILES[$z]'>$DIR_PATH_RESULT/$other_FILES[$z]</OPTION>";
                       }
                       $z++;
                   }

                   echo "</SELECT></td> </form>""
   ```
3. I used $_GET to get the variable 'dir'
   `$dir=$_GET[dir];`
4. However I got the "undefined variable"

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Doesn't `dir` need to be a string?

Comment: what does that mean? how can I modify to make it work?